# Validate that brackets are balanced

Tags: javascript, interview-questions, balanced-delimiters

I've done a test for a job (which I failed) and I'd like to know in which ways my code could've been better.

Here are the questions and my answers, it's not very long.

> 1) Make a program that checks if a string has balanced parentheses or
>   brackets.
>
> - Braces: (), [], <>
> - For every closing brace, there must've been an opening, and for every open there must be a closure
> - return 1 if it's balanced, or 0 if it isn't

My code:

```
const verify = (string) => {

    // Array of the type of braces
    var braces = ["(", ")", "[", "]", "<", ">"];
    // Array half the length of braces Array
    var balanced = Array.apply(null, {length: braces.length/2}).map(function() { return 0; });

    for(let i = 0; i < string.length; ++i) {
        let char = string[i], braceIndex = braces.indexOf(char);

        if ( braceIndex == -1 ) { 
            // If current char is not any type of brace, continue.
            continue;
        }

        // Get the index of the brace found halved and floored
        let braceBalancingIndex = braceIndex / 2, braceFloor = Math.floor( braceBalancingIndex );

        // If the halved index is equal to the index, then it must be an opening, else it must be a closing
        if (braceBalancingIndex == braceFloor) {
            balanced[braceFloor]++;
        }
        else {
            balanced[braceFloor]--;
        }

        // If at any type being, the balance is negative, there was a closing without opening
        for(let j = 0; j < balanced.length; ++j) {
            if (balanced[j] < 0) return 0;
        }

    }

    // If at the end the string is not balanced, there where more openings than closings
    for(let i = 0; i < balanced.length; ++i) {
        if (balanced[i] != 0) return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Note that the accepted solution actually does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At its heart, this is a stack problem.  You can get O(n) worst-case performance and O(n) space complexity by simply iterating the string in place, pushing opening brackets onto a stack and when encountering a closing bracket, popping the last item off stack to compare against.

You need to end up with an empty stack, and you can never have a case where you try to read out of an empty stack.  This in addition, of course to making sure items you are comparing out of the stack match appropriately.  So, there are three failure scenarios.

The solution I present might technically be optimized by hard-coding the opening and closing bracket values into conditionals and such, but I find this solution more flexible and easier to maintain from a code standpoint, as you have decoupled the bracket "configuration" from the code logic.

```
var balanced = '({[test string](test [string])})';
var unbalanced = '{()}]';
var empty = '';

var bracketConfig = [
    { left: '{', right: '}' },
    { left: '[', right: ']' },
    { left: '(', right: ')' }
];

function isBalanced(subject, bracketConfig) {
    // not shown - perhaps validate subject as string and error out if failing

    // build bracket arrays from config
    var openingChars = [];
    var closingChars = [];
    bracketConfig.forEach( (item) => {
        openingChars.push(item.left);
        closingChars.push(item.right);
    });

    var stack = [];
    for (var i = 0, len = subject.length; i < len; i++) {
        var char = subject[i];
        var openIdx = openingChars.indexOf(char);
        var closeIdx = closingChars.indexOf(char);
        if (openIdx > -1) {
            stack.push(openIdx);
        } else if (closeIdx > -1) {            
            if (stack.length === 0) return 0;
            lastIdx = stack.pop();
            if(lastIdx !== closeIdx) return 0;
        }
    }

    if (stack.length !== 0) return 0;
    return 1;     
}

// run tests
console.log(isBalanced(balanced, bracketConfig));
console.log(isBalanced(unbalanced, bracketConfig));
console.log(isBalanced(empty, bracketConfig));
```

[JSFiddle of this example](https://jsfiddle.net/595yjLyh/)

My guess is that, for your interview, they were **really** looking to see that you could identify this as a stack problem and come up with a reasonable implementation.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the specification never explicitly states that the delimiters must nest properly, even though that is a requirement in the classic [tag:balanced-delimiters] problem. Perhaps the poster failed the interview for failing to seek clarification about the requirements.

Comment: Why is `lastIdx` a global variable?

Answer (score 4):

### Simple balanced brace checker.

The quickest way to solve the problem is to use the Javascript RegExp (regular expression) It is used to search strings. It is a complicated object to master but well worth the effort as it will save you 100's of lines of code.

To solve if some string `str` has balanced braces you need two regular expressions 
and some assumptions

- If there are no brace characters then the string is balanced
- If the total number of braces is an odd number the string can not be balanced
- If after removing all non brace characters you can not find a pair of facing braces (eg facing pair `[]`) then it is not balanced
- A balanced str with non brace characters removed will always have at least one facing pair of braces.

Using those rules a simple function can quickly work out if a string is balances. It will not have to iterate (the do while loop) any more than the depth of the deepest nested braces.

**As a complete function**

```
function parenthesesAreBalanced (str) {
    var len;
    var reduceRegExp = /(\[\])|(\(\))|(<>)/g; // to remove facing pairs

    str = str.replace(/[^\[\]\(\)<>]+/g,""); // remove all non parentheses
    if (str.length === 0) { return 1; }      // no braces balanced
    if (str.length % 2) { return 0; }        // odd length then not balanced.
    do { // Remove facing pairs until there are no more to remove.
        len = str.length;
        str = str.replace(reduceRegExp, ""); // remove all facing pairs
    } while (len !== str.length)
    if (str.length === 0) { return 1; }      // Balanced and good. :)
    return 0;                                // UnBalanced and bad. :(
}
```

**As a parallel solution.**

With not to much effort the regexp searches can be done on the GPU via webGL making this solution a highly parallel solution.

Thus the max cycle count is the depth of the deepest matching pair + 1. That can be no more than `str.length / 2 + 1;`

Comment: I wish I could master regular expressions, thanks for the contribution.

Comment: This would seem to unnecessarily iterate over the subject string.  There is no reason you should ever need to read the characters out of the string more than once, as is happening here by repeated calls to `replace()`.  Also while regex certainly give you a powerful tool for working with strings, I don't know that it is needed here. Depending on javascript engine running this code, the regex may or may not introduce unnecessarily slow approach vs. simple string manipulation.

Comment: @MikeBrant for those that know how to use regExp this function is less complex than other solutions. I have a reasonable assumption that any string manipulation technique will not perform as well. This would be more so if the set of parentheses were to be extended and function seen as of n characters check if n types of open/close delimiters are balanced. Personally the c++ answer is by far the best here but sadly javascript is not a safe language for recursion (until tail call optimization is standard). I will test all the functions here for performance.

Comment: @Blindman67 My concern is not so much the regex performance itself, but rather the repeated iteration over the string that is inherent in this approach.  Every time you call the `replace()` function you iterate the string (or what remains of it), meaning that you can end up "touching" (reading out, comparing against regex, etc.) each of the bracket characters in the string multiple times, which isn't really necessary.  On complex strings with many levels of bracket nesting this could begin to show performance problems compared to single iteration through string.  But as always, test and see.

Comment: @Blindman67 And I would agree that this approach is not "complex" in terms of being able to read and understand it, I am concerned more with operational complexity. I would appear this solution is O(n log n) vs. O(n). This doesn't mean an O(n) solution will necessarily perform better though as we are talking "worst case" here and we have variables such as the javascript engine, typical type of strings that are expected to be passed to this function, etc. that can all impact real-world performance.  Thus the need to test in the real world.

Comment: @MikeBrant  The cost is only as deep as the deepest nesting pair. Or less if it fails. I have just compared the performance of the RegExp version and the string iteration method comparing randomly generated ~5000 (code/page sized) balanced and unbalanced strings The question of performance is important when you consider the difference with the regExp being 5 times quicker. If you also take into account that the most likely result is to return balanced that becomes 11 times quicker.

Comment: @MikeBrant there is also the argument of parallel processing. The task via your approach is sequential. While the two regexp can easily be implemented in parallel. That would reduce the time solve to depth of the deepest nested pair + 1. In terms of cycle count  the max cycle count would be `string length / 2 + 1` and as the GPU is ubiquitous and accessible via javascript it is not unreasonable to say that my function need only to change the regexp to a parallel implementation

Comment: @Blindman67 Great conversation.  I ran some test cases as well, and I can validate your findings.  I am convinced that (at least on my Chrome browser) that the uses cases where regex really shines are the larger more complex balanced input strings.  Where the string iteration approach seems to potentially perform better are for unbalanced inputs where the breaking syntax error happens earlier in the string (I would need to run more randomized tests to better understand where a "breakeven" point may be). So it might come down to testing with data the OP really expects the application to handle.

Comment: @Blindman67 But it seems the regex approach performs consistently better across a range of use cases.  A great proof point for those reading as to why testing matters and why sometimes you might need to implement seemingly simple functions like this in a couple of different ways to understand what works better for your use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a lot of experience with JavaScript, so I'll write a pseudo-code algorithm for you that would be a little more efficient.

```
function IsBalanced(inputString) {

    var parenCount, bracketCount, angleCount = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < inputString.Length; i++) {

        var checkChar = inputString[i];

        parenCount += (checkChar == '(' ? 1 : 0);
        parenCount -= (checkChar == ')' ? 1 : 0);
        bracketCount += (checkChar == '[' ? 1 : 0);
        bracketCount -= (checkChar == ']' ? 1 : 0);
        angleCount += (checkChar == '<' ? 1 : 0);
        angleCount -= (checkChar == '>' ? 1 : 0);

        if (parenCount < 0 || bracketCount < 0 || angleCount < 0)
            return 0;
    }

    return ((parenCount + bracketCount + angleCount) != 0 ? 0 : 1);
}
```

Or, without the ternary operators:

```
function IsBalanced(inputString) {

    var parenCount, bracketCount, angleCount = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < inputString.Length; i++) {

        var checkChar = inputString[i];

        if (checkChar == '(') parenCount++;
        if (checkChar == ')') parenCount--;
        if (checkChar == '[') bracketCount++;
        if (checkChar == ']') bracketCount--;
        if (checkChar == '<') angleCount++;
        if (checkChar == '>') angleCount--;

        if (parenCount < 0 || bracketCount < 0 || angleCount < 0)
            return 0;
    }

    if (parenCount != 0) return 0;
    if (bracketCount != 0) return 0;
    if (angleCount != 0) return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

So what is happening here is you know that for every open bracket there must be a close, so if we count all the opens, and subtract all the closes, that resulting number must equal zero.

Comment: Thanks! This is the idea, but each brace type must have its own balance, I mean, you can't close ( with >

Comment: You are right, let me modify it...

Comment: This is good too, but in the case that during the string there where closing brackets without openings this would return true. For example, the string `']][['` would evaluate as balanced, but it isn't.

I get the idea, in concept is very similar to what I've done but more specific to the braces asked alone.

**For every closing brace, there must've been an opening**

Comment: Ok, a simple modification. If any of the counts goes negative, then return 1 immediately.

Comment: Well, this might be what was expected, cleaner, simpler, in the core its the same concept, count the balance of each type of brace, but without the maths bit that gave the script the posibility of just adding any number of brace types just adding them to the braces array. Thanks for your time

Comment: When you do these tests remember that the interviewer is asking for the absolute simplest way to complete the task at hand. Don't design in possibilities that aren't in the spec, or make it any more difficult than necessary. Remember you are being evaluated not only for skill, but the ability to crank out code that is easily maintainable and understandable. Complicated code is hard to maintain and test.

Comment: In JavaScript, it should be `inputString.length`, not `inputString.Length`. Also, by convention, the function name should be `isBalanced`.

Comment: The return values are just the opposite of the specification.

Comment: @200_success Thanks, I fixed the return values. In the top of the post though I mentioned that this is more pseudo-code than JS. I can read JS a whole lot better than I can write it (obviously).

Comment: This doesn't work. Consider `{[(])}`  In this case, none of your counters would ever go below 0 in your loop to trigger failure, but all counters would end up at 0, giving a false positive.  Counters are not enough.  Order in which opening/closing brackets are encountered matters.  The thought of simply iterating over the string is the directionally correct approach however.

Comment: @MikeBrant That is a deficiency that was present in the original code — an issue that should be pointed out in a new answer.

Comment: @MikeBrant To be fair, its also not a requirement. Only that they are balanced and facing, what you are talking about is a syntax checking method, which I believe would have been out of scope for this interview question.

Answer (score -1):

The solution that I presented was using stack push and pop method. There are some givens that we know it going to fail:

1. The last bracket must be a closing bracket otherwise, it fails.
2. The first bracket must be an opening bracket otherwise, it fails.
3. It must be an even number since bracket must be in pairs.

The solution I implemented was to push from last closing bracket into 
balanced stack until it reaches opening bracket, then it must pair up with
with closing bracket in the balanced stack, if it doesn't match at top of balanced stack then it fails. If it matches then pop the closing bracket off the balanced stack. The balanced stack only stores closing brackets. `arr` is an array that stores all brackets that need to be iterated through from last to first bracket. The balanced bracket must be empty at the end in order to pass.

```
var open  = ['[','<','('];
var close = [']','>',')'];

var isBalanced = function(br){
  let balanced = [];

  let arr = br.replace(/[^\(\)\<\>\[\]]/g,'').split(''); //brackets only

    if(arr.length % 2 !== 0) return 0; // must be an even pair

    for(let i=arr.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        if(close.indexOf(arr[i])>=0) //check if it is a closing bracket
            balanced.push(arr[i]);
        else{  // if bracket match, then pop off balanced array
            if(open.indexOf(arr[i])!==close.indexOf(balanced[balanced.length-1]))
                return 0;
            else
                balanced.pop();
        }
    }
    return (balanced.length>0)?0:1;
};

console.log(isBalanced('<>[ccg[<a>]]b([09])'));   // 1
console.log(isBalanced('<[[<>>]]([])'));          // 0
console.log(isBalanced('][<>]]([])'));            // 0
console.log(isBalanced('foo(bar);'));             // 1
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/dehihasabe/2/edit?js,console

Answer (score -1):

a bit late but anyway, there is my vision. Absolutely straightforward, stack-based approach. Comparing with other stack-based solutions this one is easy to read and understand. Possibly one would like to add checking for subject string without braces at all (using RegExp or other means) to avoid unnecessary iterating through input string. Not sure however if using RegExp will be faster than iterating

```
function verify(txt)
{
    if (!txt) return 1;

    var stack = [];
    var n = txt.length;
    while (n--)
    {
        switch (txt.charAt(n))
        {
            case ')': stack.unshift(')'); break;
            case ']': stack.unshift(']'); break;
            case '>': stack.unshift('>'); break;
            case '<':
                if (stack.shift() === '>') break;
                return 0;
            case '[':
                if (stack.shift() === ']') break;
                return 0;
            case '(':
                if (stack.shift() === ')') break;
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return +(stack.length === 0);
}
```

**UPD** This solution is focused on the being as simple and straightforward (also easy to read and understand) as possible. For the 'under hood' logic you can check Mike Brant's answer above (or Ctrl+F for 'At its heart, this is a stack problem')

Because of its simplicity we also getting runtime gain 30% (FF.61) to 70% (Chromium 68.0), see [jsperf:braces-balance](https://jsperf.com/braces-balance)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please explain your reasoning (how your solution works and why it is better than the original) so that the author and other readers can learn from your thought process. Please read [Why are alternative solutions not welcome?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8404/120114) - [From Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/103162)

Comment: Just down-voting will not help to improve the answer :( I propose that any careful reader did not miss great explanation of the 'magic' behind stack-based approach by Mike Brant (just scroll up a few or Ctrl+F for 'At its heart, this is a stack problem').  On the dark side Mike's solution is over engineered, and unexact as well (note OP question brackets pairs and Mike's solution pairs). One can want to compare runtime metrics of those two solutions [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/braces-balance): proposed solution has almost 30% gain comparing with original one (FF.61)

Comment: As for being over engineered I mean that there is an exact question for exact conditions, not looking for extensible one. And moreover, at when I was solving this exact question, there was an explicit statement:  "You need to consider three kinds: (), [], <> and only these kinds". Imagine, chinese developer will add also add 【】pair, and maybe even 左右 pair. Indian guy will add something else, etc. We have an exact question and need to provide an exact solution. Again, the answer is focused on the being as straightforward and easy to read and understand as possible, as a bonus we get 30% gain